# Top margin for using Autolayout iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, autolayout, visual-format-language

I have create two UIViews programatically and want to implement Visual Format language Autolayout , I want to user NSLayoutFormatAlignAllTop for both views,
Below is my code-

```
-(void)doCodeForWidthAndHeight
{
    UIView *myView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    myView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    myView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;  //This part hung me up
    [self.view addSubview:myView];

    UIView *mySecondView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    mySecondView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    mySecondView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;  //This part hung me up
    [self.view addSubview:mySecondView];

    NSDictionary *viewsDictionary = @{@"myView":myView,@"mySecond":mySecondView};

    // 1. Create a dictionary of views
    NSArray *constraint_POS_V = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-200-[myView(100)]-[mySecond(100)]" options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDictionary];

    NSArray *constraint_POS_H = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-20-[myView(40)]-40-[mySecond]-30-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDictionary];

    NSArray *topMargin = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"[myView]-[mySecond]" options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllTop metrics:nil views:viewsDictionary];

    [self.view addConstraints:constraint_POS_H];
    [self.view addConstraints:constraint_POS_V];
    [self.view addConstraints:topMargin];
}
```

[image: This is the result of my current code and result is correct, but i can see some warning message in log]

Pelase suggest how can i use NSLayoutFormatAlignAllTop option in my current code.
Error in log are
Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "",
    ""
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in  may also be helpful.
2016-08-05 20:12:41.763 FamilyApp[12908:242194] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "",
    "",
    ""
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in  may also be helpful.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?  Your first constraint says you want to the first view to be above the second one which makes no sense if you want their tops to be aligned.

Comment: Yes i know somewhere i am wrong, please suggest me what is the solution of this

Answer (score 2):

You're simultaneously saying your views are next to each other horizontally AND on top of each other vertically. That's impossible.

Comment: Thnx ZaBlanc, I can see that there is conflict. Please let me know what is the most accurate solution of this scenarios. I just want top allignment